# cloud and existing enterprise applications technologies

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure, cloud

1. What is the significance of new cloud platforms and databases like Microsoft Azure and Amazon EC2?
2. Is it a replacement for enterprise application platforms like .net or Java EE in a cloud environment?
3. Is it neccessary to use these or other cloud specific platforms, or can we implement .net or Java EE on a cloud based environment?

Answer (score 1):

I think the comparison is not correct to some extent. Cloud is a deployment issue and J2EE Technologies is a development issue. 
The idea of clouds was to take away the hardware costs for existing application which have been build on J2EE or .NET or any other application development framework.

Yes when you deploy your applications in clud, there are some changes and some deployment strategies which would enforce some change in your application but application would still be J2EE or .NET as was the case before

Comment: yes, I do know that this is a deployment issue.
But my question is specific to the new platforms on the block, like Azure or EC2.
Where does this stand vs the development platforms.
Eg: some hosting providers have cloud servers. I can modify existing or make new applications in .net/JEE and deploy on these servers. I understand that perfectly.
What I dont understand is the significance on new cloud platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I see two kinds of clouds, those that offer their own programming model and those that host applications developed in an existing programming model. Give the choice I would prefer the latter, I don't want to redevelop my existing apps and I want to sure that I'm free to host my app on my choice of host.

As it happens I'm a Java EE developer and there are Java EE clouds, so I'm OK. So for me Azure has little immediate significance other that to reinforce the message that serious vendors see a future for cloud computing.

Now, what is Azure? Is it a hoster of .NET apps, or is it offering a different programmng model? Or Both? I'm finding it hard to determine from the various web sites and reviews. There's talk of .NET programming an C# and VB and maybe other languages and using existing tooling, so my current guess is that .NET developers will be at home, but perhaps need to adapt their style.

My tentative opinion: if I'm a doing .NET I'll keep doing it and expect to find a suitable cloud one day. If Azure is that cloud (and I'd want to find out) well and good, if not then I'll wait for something better.

In a serious enterprise space I don't need to back a winner in a market place that's still evolving. I probably will have sensitive apps that I'm not going to put in a public cloud anyway, so sticking to Java EE suits me fine, I've got private cloud capabilities if I need them.

Comment: The first kind is also called PaaS (Platform as a service), the second kind is called IaaS(Infrastructure as a service).

Answer (score 0):

EC2 is kind of a hybrid; at its root it's a hosted virtual machine service that lets you choose the operating system you want (most Linux distributions, Solaris or a couple of versions of Windows Server) and then configure them as you like without restrictions.

On top of that, Amazon has built services such as Simple DB, Simple Queue Service and Simple Notification Service that make it into more of a development platform, but it's important to note that these run cross-platform and can be programmed to in multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

A link to Windows Azure's *Tomcat Solution Accelerator* can be found on MSDN's ["Windows Azure Platform"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/default.aspx) landing page where you will also find links to the following:

Windows Azure SDK for Java

Windows Azure SDK for PHP

Windows Azure Tools for Eclipse

AppFabric SDK for Java™ Developers

AppFabric SDK for Ruby Developers

AppFabric SDK for PHP Developers

As well as...

MySQL PHP Solution Accelerator

MediaWiki MySQL Solution Accelerator